# log execution of certain commands on linux

Tags: linux, bash, debian, logging, monitoring

I have to maintain a system (debian) on which several users are allowed to install programs - so I would like to log, for example, if anyone executes "apt-get install" or "apt-get purge", so I can keep track of manually installed packages..

I'm looking for a general way to achieve this; it's not just APT, but several programs/scripts etc.

Any ideas?

**/edit**

a google-search with few different keywords brought up this:

https://serverfault.com/questions/201221/how-to-log-every-linux-command-to-a-logserver

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698590/how-to-capture-all-the-commands-typed-in-unix-linux-by-any-user

http://sourceforge.net/projects/rootsh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the [GNU Accounting Utilities (acct)](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct) are designed for.

See:

- [acct(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/acct.2.html)
- [acct(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acct.5.html)
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can work for your needs, if the users uses sudo for installing packages try this:

```
$ sudo cat auth.log | grep sudo(or apt-get or any other program/script)
```

You can also print the results to a file and create a cronjob for this.

EDIT:

Disable "sudo su" for simplifying the logging.

```
1. Use visudo for editing the sudoers file.
2. Add a line like this one: Cmnd_Alias  SUCMD = /bin/su
3. Be sure to use !SUCMD for the user or system privileges: %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL,!SUCMD
```

Comment: thanks Abrahamsson! just like many other approaches, this wouldn't log everything after "sudo su".I've been at a loss yesterday; a google-search with few different keywords brought up this:

http://serverfault.com/questions/201221/how-to-log-every-linux-command-to-a-logserver
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698590/how-to-capture-all-the-commands-typed-in-unix-linux-by-any-user
http://sourceforge.net/projects/rootsh/

Comment: Seems like the easiest way is to disable "sudo su" i will edit my post for that.

Comment: thanks for your mail! again, one could slip out of this, eg. by starting a shell in emacs or vi or whatever. i'll take a closer look on gnu acct, as nod suggested; think that would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

[Snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy) is simple to start with.

If you need more (in terms of reliability or 'uncircumventiability'), you should look towards proper auditing solutions.

Disclosure: Snoopy maintainer here.